# PHP Convert to time() "3:30 pm Wed 25 Mar" but can't get hours minutes

Tags: php, datetime

It seems that I'm just missing something. I'm trying to convert this to time() but I'm not getting the hours and minutes.

```
<?php
$ss = '3:30 pm Wed 25 Mar';
echo $ss;
echo '<hr />';
echo strtotime($ss); // 1427212800
```

But 1427212800 translates to Wednesday, March 25th 2015, 00:00:00 (GMT +8)

How can I get the hours and minutes? Thanks

Comment: Can you change the format of `$ss`? I think it's the`Wed` that is breaking it. `3:30 pm 25 Mar` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than make PHP guess at what format you're trying to feed into it, use: [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). This gives you back a full-on DateTime object, which is handy for other things...and you get a timestamp with it as well:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('g:i a D j M', '3:30 pm Wed 25 Mar')
        ->getTimeStamp(); // 1427315400
```

With this, you lose the ability to guess at multiple date formats, but it'll work just fine with the format you gave.

Comment: There's an error = Class DateTime not found. Do I need to download and  include the DateTime class? Thanks

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? DateTime requires 5.2 or above...if you're using an older version, please upgrade as they've been unmaintained for years.

Comment: Thanks @iansltx it worked. I'm using laravel 5 and just used use DateTime; above the controller class declaration and it worked.